# how to run mysql_upgrade on windows

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

I have just upgraded (uninstall, restart, download new installer and installed) MySQL Server for Windows on my 2008 R2 box.

In the upgrade procedure webpage it says:

> To use mysql_upgrade, make sure that the server is running, and then
> invoke it like this:
>
> `shell> mysql_upgrade [options]`

But I can't figure that bit out...
I'm probably having a mental blank but if I run mysql_upgrade; through the mysql command line client, I get an error 1064: you have an error in your sql syntax etc...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you already have the latest version?

Comment: Mostly what you're doing wrong is asking in the wrong place. Yours is not a programming issue. You'd do better on, perhaps, [serverFault](http://serverfault.com), but [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com) might be a good place.

Comment: I do, but the mysql_upgrade command is supposed to upgrade the databases (schemas) and is to be run AFTER installing the new version... yeah?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to start CLI as Administrator and execute the C:...\mysql_upgrade.exe --user ... --password parameters. Windows server 2012 R2 and MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0):

go to... (Assuming 64 bit mySQL)
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin

run (assuming root is the admin account)
mysql_upgrade -u root -p

Enter password when prompted